# AccessDeniedException en el token JWT Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

He creado un sistema de autenticación en Springboot, que comprueba el usuario, si existe, creo un token jwt que envía al front y el front lo devuelve para hacer peticiones, este token lleva incorporado EL rol.

```
private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "auth";

static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, Authentication authentication) {

   String token = Jwts.builder()
    .setSubject(authentication.getName())

    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout))

    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key)
    .claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authentication.getAuthorities()) // El rol es "ROLE_Consulta"
    .compact();
    res.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

}

Para el usuario que estoy usando, su rol es consulta, entonces añado en el controlador:

```
@Secured("ROLE_Consulta")
```

Entonces cuando desde el front envío el token, intento descomponerlo para crear al usuario de acceso al sistema:

```
**EDITO:**

static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Obtenemos el token que viene en el encabezado de la peticion
    String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    // si hay un token presente, entonces lo validamos
    if (token != null) {
        String user = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer", "")) // este metodo es el que valida
                .getBody().getSubject();

             Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                        .setSigningKey(key)
                        .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer", "")) 
                        .getBody();

             Collection authorities  = Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
                            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return user != null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities) : null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ve en la imagen, tengo el rol de ROLE_Consulta, pero obtengo el error de AccessDeniedException.

```
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"exception": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException",
"message": "Acceso denegado",
```

Comment: Creo que tienes una errata: El header suele tener el formato `Bearer <token>`. Por tanto, en el `replace` deberías añadir un espacio: `token.replace("Bearer ", "")`. Otra opción era `token.split(" ")[1]` o incluso `token.substring(7)` (`"Bearer "` son 7 caracteres, el espacio está en la posición 6)

Comment: Sip, he cambiado la forma de obtener el token, entonces ya obtengo el rol pero estoy obteniendo el error de que no es un usuario válido, ¿qué me puede estar fallando?

Comment: Miraré a ver... pero edita el título y el resto de la pregunta si vas a reusarla (no lo veo mal porque la primera versión iba a ser cerrada por ser un error tipográfico). Elimina el asunto del token porque ya no es relevante

Comment: Ya está todo modificado,¿ sabes porqué creando al usuario con authorities  dice que no tiene permisos ? ¿ quizás es porque es un array dentro de un array ? Pero así lo veo en otras págs webs.. no entiendo cuál es el problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto descomponiendo el authorities y obteniendo el rol y después insertando otra clase diferente al UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, No es muy elegante, pero funciona.

```
         Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(key)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer", "")) // este metodo es el que valida
                    .getBody();
         String user = claims.get("sub").toString();
         Collection authorities  = Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        String rol = "forbidden";

        for (Iterator iterator = authorities.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority type = (SimpleGrantedAuthority) iterator.next();   
            rol = type.getAuthority();
        }


        String[] splitRol = rol.split("=");
        rol = splitRol[1];
        rol = rol.substring(0, rol.length() -2);

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol));

    // Recordamos que para las demás peticiones que no sean /login
    // no requerimos una autenticacion por username/password
    // por este motivo podemos devolver un UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken sin
    // password
    return user != null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, grantedAuths) : null;
```